# How to get ID of the first table in a join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, web

I am able to get the id of the table books using the code below but how should I get the id of my fist table which is named reservation.

```
$data=reservation::where('user_id',$id)
                ->join('books','reservations.books_id','=', 'books.id')
                ->get();
```

This is how I display the value of both table. I am able to get and display data from both table.

```
@foreach($data as $data)
<tr>
    <td align="center">{{$data->borrowed_books}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{$data->price}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{$data->reserved_qty}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{$data->books_fee}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{url('/deletemenu',$data->id)}}">CANCEL</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The problem is, every time I click cancel to delete it from database the id that it gets is from the books table but I want the id of reservation table. What should I do to delete the id of reservation table instead of books table.

```
public function deletemenu($id)
{
    $data=reservation::find($id); //it used to be $data=books::find($id);
    $data->delete();
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: SQL cannot return 2 columns with the same name, so you have to use an alias for at least one of the columns in the SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $data=reservation::where('user_id',$id)
            ->join('books','reservations.books_id','=', 'books.id')
            ->select('reservations.*', 'books.*')
            ->get();
```

if you have any columns that have the same name then in your select specify the column as so lets say both tables have column ID

```
  $data=reservation::where('user_id',$id)
            ->join('books','reservations.books_id','=', 'books.id')
            ->select('reservations.*', 'books.id as book_id')
            ->get();
```